# How to skip initial Whitespace (on first line of input) in antlr3 XML Parser

Tags: xml, parsing, whitespace, antlr3

I'm trying antlr3 for the first time, and I'm experimenting with the following XML Lexer and Parser from these websites:

https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/1.+Lexer
https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/2.+Parser

```
lexer grammar XMLLexer;

@members {
    boolean tagMode = false;
}

TAG_START_OPEN : '<' { tagMode = true; } ;
TAG_CLOSE : '>' { tagMode = false; } ;

PCDATA : {!tagMode}?=> (~'<')+ ;

GENERIC_ID : {tagMode}?=> ( LETTER | '_' | ':') (NAMECHAR)* ;


fragment NAMECHAR
    : LETTER | DIGIT | '.' | '-' | '_' | ':'
;

fragment DIGIT
    :    '0'..'9'
;

fragment LETTER
    : 'a'..'z'
    | 'A'..'Z'
;

WS  :  {tagMode}?=>
       (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {channel=99;}
;

parser  grammar XMLParser;

options {      tokenVocab=XMLLexer; }
document  : element ;

element
: startTag
    (element
    | PCDATA
    )*
    endTag
| emptyElement
;

startTag  : TAG_START_OPEN GENERIC_ID (attribute)* TAG_CLOSE ;

attribute  : GENERIC_ID ATTR_EQ ATTR_VALUE ;

endTag :  TAG_END_OPEN GENERIC_ID TAG_CLOSE ;

emptyElement : TAG_START_OPEN GENERIC_ID  (attribute)* TAG_EMPTY_CLOSE ;
```

When I run then generated Lexer/Parser with the following input, it works fine.

```
<t attr="value"/>
```

However, if I insert blanks (whitespace) at the beginning of the first line,
the Parser doesn't accept it.  For example:

```
    <t attr="value"/>
```

The whitepace skipping doesn't appear to work, before the beginning of the first line, although it does work on subsequent lines.

The target output is C++.  The only change I make the grammar was to use
$channel=99 instead of channel=99, since 'channel' was not defined.

Here is the error message:
test.input(1)  : error 2 : Unexpected token, at offset , -1
    near [Index: 0 (Start: 536901896-Stop: 536901897) ='  ', type<11> Line: 1 LinePos:-1]
 : cannot match to any predicted input...

Any help would be appreciated.